# Linear vs nonlinear neural network?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I'm new to machine learning and neural networks. I know how to build a nonlinear classification model, but my current problem has a continuous output. I've been searching for information on neural network regression, but all I encounter is information on **linear** regression - nothing about **nonlinear** cases. Which is odd, because why would someone use neural networks to solve a simple linear regression anyway? Isn't that like killing a fly with a nuclear bomb?

So my question is this: what makes a neural network nonlinear? (Hidden layers? Nonlinear activation function?) Or do I have a completely wrong understanding of the word "linear" - can a linear regression NN accurately model datasets that are more complex than y=aX+b? Is the word "linear" used just as the opposite of "logistic"?

(I'm planning to use TensorFlow, but the TensorFlow Linear Model Tutorial uses a binary classification problem as an example, so that doesn't help me either.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For starters, a neural network can model any function (not just linear functions) Have a look at this - http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap4.html.

A Neural Network has got non linear activation layers which is what gives the Neural Network a non linear element.

The function for relating the input and the output is decided by the neural network and the amount of training it gets. If you supply two variables having a linear relationship, then your network will learn this as long as you don't overfit. Similarly, a complex enough neural network can learn any function.

Answer (score 27):

**WARNING: I do not advocate the use of linear activation functions only, especially in simple feed forward architectures.**

Okay, I think I need to take some time and rewrite this answer explicitly because many people are misinterpreting the point I am trying to make.

First let me point out that we can talk about **linearity in parameters or linearity in the variables**.

**The activation function is NOT necessarily what makes a neural network non-linear (technically speaking).**

For example, notice that the following regression predicted values are considered linear predictions, despite non-linear transformations of the inputs because the output constitutes a linear combination of the **parameters** (although this model is non-linear in its variables):

[image: formula]

Now for simplicity, let us consider a single neuron, single layer neural network:

[image: formula]

If the transfer function is linear then:

[image: formula]

As you have already probably noticed, this is a linear regression.  Even if we were to add multiple inputs and neurons, each with a linear activation function, we would now only have an ensemble of regressions (all linear in their parameters and therefore this simple neural network is linear):

[image: formula]

Now going back to (3), let's add two layers, so that we have a neural network with 3 layers, one neuron each (both with linear activation functions):

[image: formula] (first layer)

[image: formula] (second layer)

Now notice:

[image: formula]

Reduces to:

[image: formula]

Where [image: formula] and [image: formula]

Which means that our two layered network (each with a single neuron) is **not** linear in its parameters **despite every activation function in the network being linear; however, it is still linear in the variables.**  Thus, once training has finished the model will be linear in both variables and parameters.  Both of these are important because you cannot replicate this simple two layered network with a single regression and still capture all the effects of the model.  **Further, let me state clearly: if you use a model with multiple layers there is no guarantee that the output will be non-linear in it's variables (if you use a simple MLP perceptron and line activation functions your picture is still going to be a line).**

That being said, let's take a look at the following statement from [@Pawu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15409191/pawu) regarding this answer:

> **The answer is very misleading and makes it sound, that we can learn non-linear relationships using only linear transformations, which is simply not true.** When we back-propagate, we take the derivative of a single weight w1 and fix everything else. Now as mentioned above, we are still moving on a linear function.

While you could argue that what @Pawu is saying is technically true, I think they are implying:

**The answer is very misleading and makes it sound, that we can learn non-linear relationships using only linear *activation functions*, which is simply not true.**

I would argue that this modified statement is wrong and can easily be demonstrated incorrect.  There is an implicit assumption being made about the architecture of the model.  It is true that if you restrict yourself to using certain network architectures that you cannot introduce non-linearities without activation functions, but that is a arbitrary restriction and does not generalize to all network models.

Let me make this concrete.  First take a simple xor problem.  This is a basic classification problem where you are attempting to establish a boundary between data points in a configuration like so:

[image: xor problem]

The kicker about this problem is that it is not linearly separable, meaning no single straight line will be able to perfectly classify.  Now if you read anywhere on the internet I am sure they will say that this problem cannot be solved using only linear activation functions using a neural network (notice nothing is said about the architecture).  This statement is only true in an extremely limited context and wrong generally.

Allow me to demonstrate.  Below is a very simple hand written neural network.  This network takes randomly generated weights between -1 and 1, an "xor_network" function which defines the architecture **(notice no sigmoid, hardlims, etc. only linear transformations of the form mX or MX + B)**, and trains using standard backward propagation:

```
#%% Packages
import numpy as np

#%% Data
data = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 0]])
np.random.shuffle(data)
train_data = data[:,:2]
target_data = data[:,2]

#%% XOR architecture
class XOR_class():

    def __init__(self, train_data, target_data, alpha=.1, epochs=10000):
        self.train_data = train_data
        self.target_data = target_data
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.epochs = epochs
        
        #Random weights
        self.W0 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(2)).T
        self.b0 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(1))
        self.W2 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(2)).T
        self.b2 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(1))

    #xor network (linear transfer functions only)
    def xor_network(self, X0):
        n0 = np.dot(X0, self.W0) + self.b0
        X1 = n0*X0
        a = np.dot(X1, self.W2) + self.b2
        return(a, X1)

    #Training the xor network
    def train(self):
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            for i in range(len(self.train_data)):
                # Forward Propagation:
                X0 = self.train_data[i]
                a, X1 = self.xor_network(X0)
        
                # Backward Propagation:
                e = self.target_data[i] - a
                s_2 = -2*e
        
                # Update Weights:
                self.W0 = self.W0 - (self.alpha*s_2*X0)
                self.b0 = self.b0 - (self.alpha*s_2)
                self.W2 = self.W2 - (self.alpha*s_2*X1)
                self.b2 = self.b2 - (self.alpha*s_2)
        
        #Restart training if we get lost in the parameter space.
        if np.isnan(a) or (a > 1) or (a < -1):
            print('Bad initialization, reinitializing.')
            self.W0 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(2)).T
            self.b0 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(1))
            self.W2 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(2)).T
            self.b2 = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(1))
            self.train()
    
    #Predicting using the trained weights.
    def predict(self, test_data):
        for i in train_data:
            a, X1 = self.xor_network(i)
            #I cut off decimals past 12 for convienience, not necessary.
            print(f'input: {i} - output: {np.round(a, 12)}')
```

Now let's take a look at the output:

```
#%% Execution
xor = XOR_class(train_data, target_data)
xor.train()
np.random.shuffle(data)
test_data = data[:,:2]
xor.predict(test_data)
```

```
input: [1 0] - output: [1.]
input: [0 0] - output: [0.]
input: [0 1] - output: [1.]
input: [1 1] - output: [0.]
```

And what do you know, I guess we can learn non-linear relationships using only linear activation functions and multiple layers (that's right classification with pure line activation functions, no sigmoid needed). . .

The only catch here is that I cut off all decimals past 12, but let's be honest 7.3 X 10^-16 is basically 0.

Now to be fair I am doing a little trick, where I am using the network connections to get the non-linear result, but that's the whole point I am trying to drive home:  **THE MAGIC OF NON-LINEARITY FOR NEURAL NETWORKS IS IN THE LAYERS, NOT JUST THE ACTIVATION FUNCTIONS**.

Thus the answer to your question, "what makes a neural network non-linear" is: **non-linearity in the parameters or, obviously, non-linearity in the variables**.

**This non-linearity in the parameters/variables comes about two ways: 1) having more than one layer with neurons in your network (as exhibited above), or 2) having activation functions that result in weight non-linearities.**

For an example on non-linearity coming about through activation functions, suppose our input space, weights, and biases are all constrained such that they are all strictly positive (for simplicity).  Now using (2) (single layer, single neuron) and the activation function [image: formula], we have the following:

[image: formula]

Which Reduces to:

[image: formula]

Where [image: formula], [image: formula], and [image: formula]

Now, ignoring what issues this neural network has, it should be clear, that at the very least, it is non-linear in the parameters and variables and that non-linearity has been introduced solely by choice of the activation function.

Finally, yes neural networks can model complex data structures that cannot be modeled by using linear models (see xor example above).

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @hH1sG0n3, non-linearity in the parameters does not follow directly from many common activation functions (e.g. sigmoid).  This is not to say that common activation functions do not make neural networks nonlinear (because they are non-linear in the variables), but that the non-linearity introduced by them is degenerate without parameter non-linearity.  For example, a single layered MLP with sigmoid activation functions will produce outputs that are non-linear in the variables in that the output is not proportional to the input, but in reality this is just an array of Generalized Linear Models.  This should be especially obvious if we were to transform the targets by the appropriate link function, where now the activation functions would be linear.  Now this is not to say that activation functions don't play an important role in the non-linearity of neural networks (clearly they do), but that their role is more to alter/expand the solution space.  Said differently, non-linearities in the parameters (usually expressed through many layers/connections) are necessary for non-degenerate solutions that go beyond regression.  When we have a model with non-linearity in the parameters we have a whole different beast than regression.

At the end of the day all I want to do with this post is point out that the "magic" of neural networks is also in the layers and to dispel the ubiquitous myth that a multilayered neural network with linear activation functions is always just a bunch of linear regressions.

Comment: `This non-linearity in the parameters comes about two ways: 1) having more than one layer with neurons in your network` but isn't this wrong, additional layers don't make network non-linear, only activation functions, as @kempy writes in his answer. If you was right then his example with two hidden layers and linear activation function would succeed/converge.

Comment: Being able to solve the 4 dot Xor problem with linear transfer functions only and multiple layers proves your statement, `additional layers don't make network non-linear, only activation functions` incorrect.

`If you was right then his example with two hidden layers and linear activation function would succeed/converge.`
Just because you found a single non-linear problem that cannot be solved with linear transfer functions does not prove that it is impossible to solve any non-linear problem with linear transfer functions only + multiple layers (again, just look at the 4 dot Xor problem).

Comment: ah, ok, this is very important, @kempy is not fully right

Comment: why does this happen? why sometimes additional layers allow solving non-linear problems, but sometimes - don't?

Comment: Well, technically, I believe any problem can be solved with linear activation functions if you have enough layers + you get lucky with the initialization + you add something to deal with vanishing gradients. Of course you'd never do this because one can just use non-linear transfer functions to get to a better solution faster. Another problem is vanishing gradients, which effectively limit the size of a given network, implying a solution using linear transfer functions is not generally feasible. So the take home is that the magic is in the layers and linear transfer functions are inefficient.

Comment: Ok, thx. Another question, why you are telling `vanishing gradients are the problem`? Why vanishing, not exploding? Vanishing appears because of long chain of sigmoid, exploding - long chain of multiplication => lots of hidden layers with linear activation => lots of multiplication during backpropagation => exploding

Comment: Exploding gradients generally are not a problem (assuming a relatively simple problem), clipping, regularization, etc. can be used to ensure a smaller step size when numerically searching for the solution. Vanishing gradients basically occur when there are too many layers for the given transfer functions and the problem is relatively noisy. If your step size is too small when numerically searching the parameter space, you'll get stuck in a multi-dimensional trough that the network cannot get out of. There are tricks around this (e.g. using residuals), but no general solutions.

Comment: Hi, I have a query here. Isn't equation(8) a linear output? I mean z_2 and b_2 are constant, so they can be added, and eventually equation (8) would transform into something like y = mx + b form which is linear?

Comment: No and Yes.  Eq. 8 is non-linear in the parameters w1, w2, b1, b2 (which is the point in the answer), but it is technically linear in the parameters z1, z2, b1.  If you were to vary z1 (given p), holding all else constant, you would be moving up and down a line.  If you were to vary w1, holding all else constant, you would be moving up and down a non-linear function.

Comment: Is a single layer MLP with sigmoid activation non-linear in its parameters? e.g., is 1/(1-e^(wp+b) going to result in multiplication of the parameters themselves? I believe logistic regression is GLM. If so, wouldn't it be more correct to say in (2) above "activation functions that result in weight multiplication"?

Comment: Yes, you are exactly correct. Although, this is where things start becoming complicated. Technically, your suggestion implies that sigmoid/ others do not introduce nonlinearities in the parameters, which one could argue is generally true; however, they do impact the "richness" of the nonlinearity introduced through multiple layers. So, in a way you could also argue that by "exaggerating" the nonlinearities of the model they are introducing nonlinearity (of course anything that makes the output not proportional to the input is a nonlinear system). I'll try to change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Pawu I made a mistake in one of my above statements.  I meant to say:  If you were to vary w1, holding z2 and b2 constant, you would be moving up and down a non-linear function.

Comment: Re-reading this fantastic reply. It strikes me as so bizarre that in the field, you can often hear people evangelising non-linear activation functions as the nn essence whilst using ReLus. So frustrating.

Comment: In your architecture definition `xor_network`, you declare a `X1=n0*X0` term. Doesn't that account as nonlinear relationship in the variables since the expression can be reduces to `X1 = W0*X0^2 + b*X0`? I have tried removing that term and adding one neuron in that same layer by instantiating a `(2,2)` `W0` but found no convergeness. Any ideas?

Comment: You are landing right on point.  First off, I should point out that technically you could argue that altering layer connections and swapping out activation functions is the same thing (e.g. one could argue activation functions are just static network layers), so at the end of the day a lot of this is moot and is just me trying to give everyone a different perspective.

Comment: X1=n0*X0 is a linear function in X0 at the point of calculation because n0 is a scalar.  However, you are completely right that really the whole thing X1 = W0*X0^2 + b*X0 is nonlinear.  But the comparison I wanted to draw was between  X1=n0*X0 and  X1=c*X0, where c is and element of R.  You see the change between these two is how I connect the layer to the activation function (keeping the structure of the activation function constant, e.g. not making it something like X1=c*X0^2).  So a lot of this comes down to semantics on how you distinguish between a layer and its activation function.

Comment: Now I can understand that the distinctions I am trying to make are silly to some, but I believe they are very important conceptually because if you see what I am trying to convey you realize that the structure neural networks can take on go far beyond their current rigid implementations.

Comment: The Xor network must contain non-linear transformations to model non-linear relationships, but I argue here that the carrier of this non-linearity is the layer connections, not some arbitrary choice of non-linear activation function.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to nonlinear regression, this is referring to how the weights affect the output. If a function is not linear with respect to the weights, then your problem is a nonlinear regression problem. So for example, let's look at a Feedforward Neural Network with one hidden layer where the activation functions in the hidden layer are some function [image] and the output layer has linear activation functions. Given this, the mathematical representation can be:

[image]

where we assume [image] can operator on scalars and vectors with this notation to make it easy. [image], [image], [image], and [image] are the weight you are aiming to estimate with the regression. If this was linear regression, [image] would equal z, because that would make y linearly dependent on [image] & [image]. But if [image] is nonlinear, say like [image], then now y is nonlinearly dependent on the weights [image].

Now provided you understand all that, I am surprised you haven't seen discussion of the nonlinear case because that's pretty much all people talk about in textbooks and research. The use of things like stochastic gradient descent, Nonlinear Conjugate Gradient, RProp, and other methods are to help find local minima (and hopefully good local minima) for these nonlinear regression problems, even though a global optimum is not typically guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Any non-linearity from the input to output makes the network non-linear. In the way we usually think about and implement neural networks, those non-linearities come from **activation functions**.

If we are trying to fit non-linear data and only have linear activation functions, our best approximation to the non-linear data will be linear since that's all we can compute. You can see an example of a neural network trying to fit **non-linear data** with only **linear activation functions** [here](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=linear&batchSize=20&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-gauss&learningRate=0.003&regularizationRate=0.001&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.87118&showTestData=false&discretize=true&percTrainData=80&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=regression&initZero=false&hideText=false).

However, if we change the **linear activation function** to something **non-linear** like **ReLu**, then we can see a better non-linear fitting of the data. You can see that [here](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=relu&batchSize=20&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-gauss&learningRate=0.003&regularizationRate=0.001&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.97957&showTestData=false&discretize=true&percTrainData=80&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=regression&initZero=false&hideText=false).

Comment: not only activation function gives non-linearity, but also hidden layers (sometimes additional layers allow solving non-linear problems, but sometimes - don't), check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61619406/3574379

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on itwasthekix post, but I want to share my insight.

1. Someone asked in the comments whether equation 8 was linear, and the
   answer was, that if w1 were to be varied when all else is constant
   we would move up and down a non-linear function. This is not true.
   When we vary w1, we essentially only change the output of `z1 = (w1*p + b1)`. Since z1 is linearly transformed later, we will still
   move an a linear function. If we were to fix everything except w1
   AND w2, then we would move on a non-linear function.
2. If a multi-layer ANN is non-linear in parameters, because we have a
   multiplication of parameters. That does not mean it can learn non-linear relationships.
3. The answer is very misleading and makes it sound, that we can
   learn non-linear relationships using only linear transformations,
   which is simply not true. When we back-propagate, we take the derivative of a single weight w1 and fix everything else. Now as mentioned above, we are still moving on a linear function.
4. If we take the gradient of `w1*w2` and perform gradient descent, we only know the joint gradient, there is no way to determine the influence of the separate parameters without fixing one of them. And if we fix one, we move on a linear function.
5. If we add an (non-linear) activation function, we linearly transform a non-linear output enabling us to learn non-linear relationships, since we do not move on a linear function anymore.
6. Lets look at the case `z = w2 * g(w1 * p + b1) + b2` assuming `g` is a non-linear activation function. Then if we fix everything and vary w1, we will move on a non-linear function, since `w1 * p + b1` is transformed by `g`.

Comment: Yeah, I needed to make my answer clearer and talk about non-linearity in the variables.  Although I disagree with some of your points, specifically: "The answer is very misleading and makes it sound, that we can learn non-linear relationships using only linear transformations, which is simply not true".  I assume you mean linear activation functions, although your statement is true if you extend your meaning of linear transformations to layers/connections as well, but that doesn't go against what I am saying.  I've updated my answer to reflect these clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Non-linearity means different things in communities of regression analysis and neural network machine learning.

In regression analysis, when we say a fitting model is nonlinear, we mean that the model is nonlinear in terms of its parameters (not in terms of the independent variables).

A multiple-layer neural network is usually nonlinear in terms of the weights even the activation function is linear. This is simple to see because the information propagating in the network corresponds to function composition: f3(f2(f1())), which generally gives nonlinear functions of weights. Therefore, in terms of regression analysis, all neural networks are nonlinear models.

However in the community of neural network, people talk about the linearity in terms of input variables, rather than the weights/biases. Therefore, they define a neutral network with linear activation functions as linear and that with nonlinear activation function as nonlinear.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same struggle, most online courses use ANNs for classification, but you never actually solve a regression problem with them in the courses.

**What does make an ANN non-linear? The activation function.**

Even if you have an ANN with thousands of perceptrons and hidden units, if all the activations are linear (or not activated at all) you are just training a plain linear regression.

But be careful, some activations functions (like sigmoid), have a range of values that act as a linear function and you may get stuck with a linear model even with non-linear activations.

**How to predict continuous output with an ANN? The same way as when you classify.**

It is the same problem, you just backpropagate the error (label - prediction) and update the weights. But don't forget to C*HANGE THE ACTIVATION FUNCTION of the output layer to a continuous function* (maybe ReLu if all labels are positive or don't activate the output at all), the intermediate hidden layers can be activated however you wish.

For small regression problems with ANNs you may need to start with a veeeeeery small learning rate since there will be lots of variance since the error will be "unbounded" at first.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to be impolite, but the current answers are all related to nonlinear ND-polynomials resulting from linear activation functions. That simply doesn't make sense in terms of this question.

I get the point because you will have a polynomial as the objective function to minimize with coefficients that are products of layer coefficients and a product is nonlinear. Anyway, such a system will never be able to converge and doesn't make sense at all without any extra constraints.

The described system is not only completely unnecessarily  nonlinear, but also ill-posed. Don't argue about stuff that leads *ad absurdum*. The original question actually completely nailed it.

Build a "linear neural network" with layers and try to use it as usual... then you will realise that this goes nowhere and you wasted your time.
So unless there is good reasons to believe this kind of ill-posed stuff has been handled I would never ever consider using a linear activation function. If you have extra constraints this might make sense. If you use stochastic gradient descent then you will at least skip some bad properties of it.

That the objective function is nonlinear in its parameters **gives an impression that is wrong and bogus**. And if the writer would have known about optimisation problems connected to terms with a product of coefficients he would have never written anything like this.

Any objective function can be made nonlinear. If you just replace one linear coefficient with a product of two coefficients. But that is nonsense because you can never determine those coefficients. NEVER. There are infinitely many solutions! And that doesn't even depend on the amount of data.

Answer (score -2):

Because the activation is w*x, which is linear operation, so you need to have extra elements to make it non-linear.